# Change box plot "boxes" percentiles displayed using matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following produces a simple box plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bp = plt.boxplot(range(10), whis=[2.2, 97.8])
```

My question is , is it possible to switch the end of the "boxes" from Q1 and Q3 (25th and 75th percentile) , to be sigma -1 and sigma 1 (~ 16% and 84%) ?

I've experimented with the whis argument which gets me 2 sigmas (what I want), and have a feeling that maybe with the "notch" or "bootstrap" args it's possible to switch the boxes as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the box in a box and whisker plot is supposed to represent the 1st/3rd quartiles. Typically the whiskers can represent other 'limits' - i've used +/- sigma before... but not sure the box should be alterable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving Custom inter quartile range for Boxplot in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911424/giving-custom-inter-quartile-range-for-boxplot-in-matplotlib)